# PdfMake, big size customized font load very slow

Tags: javascript, fonts, pdfmake

I come across one issue after I customized font in pdfMake. I already customized the font. I generated new vfs_fonts.js that contains Roboto and simfang (chinese font). The problem is the file is about 15MB and the system loads very slow for the first time because it takes much time loading that font (as I check in network tab). I have to wait for long (on production). Does anybody have solution for this ?

Comment: My friend has the same problem !!!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to generate font packages dynamically.Only put the needed word in it.But this method still not good.I'm also looking for the better method...

Comment: Just be elaborate in what you are telling which would be helpful for members who are following this question. Thank you!